# Homotopy Maps (Continuation methods)

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

The idea of continuation methods is the following:

We would like to solve a system of non-linear equations $f(x)=0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Instead of solving the problem directly, we take a look at an easy problem with an obvious solution and trace this solution back to the original problem. This is done by so-called homotopy maps.

For example:
$H(x, \lambda) = \lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)(x-a)$ where $\lambda$ is a scalar and $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

**My question:** What different kind of homotopy maps exists and what are their adventages and disadvantages? My textbook only contains the example above and I also didn't find any information online, expect that it can sometimes be better to use problem-oriented homotopy-maps....

Comment: Well, for this example a homotopy map will essentially always look like $\lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda) g(x)$; so if you can solve $g(x)=0$ then you can use that as a guess for $1/N f(x) + (1-1/N) g(x)=0$, run some algorithm a small number of steps to solve that, and repeat $N$ times. Ideally $g(x)$ is reasonably similar to $f(x)$ (at least in a small neighborhood of the two roots of interest) so that the solution doesn't change too drastically with $\lambda$ (otherwise the intermediate problems may be difficult to solve).

Comment: By the way, continuation isn't always done by homotopy maps.

Comment: Thanks! Can you give me a mathematical explanation why $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ should be similar?

And if you would like to answer this as well, what are the other continuation methods? ;)

Comment: Basically, if all is going qualitatively smoothly (i.e. you are continuously tracking a zero as $\lambda$ varies and it doesn't disappear or bifurcate), then the more quantitatively different $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are near the root you want to find, the smaller your steps in $\lambda$ will need to be in order to be able to easily solve the intermediate problems.

Comment: As for other continuation methods, this is the sort of thing that is pretty straightforward to look up. Generally other methods arise in problems that are "really" parametrized, rather than problems like yours where a parameter is artificially introduced to solve a problem that isn't really parametric.